# CSS animation using ::before class extends beyond the div

Tags: html, css

I've added a slide animation to my portfolio website homepage, and I can't figure out how or why it is extending before the confines of the div it's attached to. On hover to extends left and right of the div.

Website is http://www.helencalderon.co.uk/

And the styles I'm using are

```css
.card {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #d6d2d2;
    margin-bottom: 2.8125%;
    max-width: 714px
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 714px) {
    .card {
        margin:0 auto 2.8125% auto
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .card {
        display:flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: row;
        max-width: none
    }
}

.card::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    z-index: 2;
    display: block;
    content: '';
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.3) 100%);
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-25deg);
    transform: skewX(-25deg)
}

.card:hover::before {
    -webkit-animation: shine 2s;
    animation: shine 2s
}
```

Comment: Please re-read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) especially the line `Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself` <= links do not count as "provide all parts"

Comment: Sorry :( I left out a bit by accident Thank you @Deykun

Answer (score 1):

You are placing your ::before at the left of your container with `left: -100%;`, and you are moving it to the `left: 125%;` (so it's placed to the right after the animation is finished - you move it to the right 125% width of your container). Using `transform: skewX(-25deg)` is also making your ::before wider.

To cut all things escaping from your `.card` you can add `overflow: hidden;` to it.